# Ввод массива используя функции

Tags: c++, массивы

День добрый. Имеются функции.

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

void scanArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << " element: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

И в main

```
    int main()
{
    int n,k,m;
    int i,j,temp;
    int dn=2*n,dm=2*m;
    int counter = 0;
    int c=n;

    counter = 0;

    cout << "Enter n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter k" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Enter m" << endl;
    cin >> m;

    int arr[n];


    scanArray(arr,dm);
    printArray(arr,dm);


    return 0;
};
```

Если вводить массив без функции, то все нормально. А если используя функцию, то он не ограничивается. Т.е. я ввожу значения и вывод не происходит. Бесконечный ввод грубо говоря.

Comment: Этот код даже компилироваться не должен...

Comment: Так у вас `dm` не инициализируется ничем разумным.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему это?

Comment: @retorta, `cin >> n;` и `int arr[n];` - в плюсах так нельзя. Да и без плюсов можно далеко не везде. А тут cin/cout.

Comment: @CppBeginner ну так выведите: `void scanArray(int arr[], int size)
{ cout << size; ...`

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну с точки зрения стандарта это правда, конечно, но и `gcc`, и, кажется, `clang` такое вполне проглатывают.

Comment: @retorta, да, ест: http://ideone.com/Ll6MtZ

Comment: Переменная m в выражении dm=2*m не инициализирована

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> int dn=2*n,dm=2*m;
> int counter = 0;
> int c=n;
>
> counter = 0;
> ```

Удалить.

> ```
> scanArray(arr,dm);
> printArray(arr,dm);
> ```

```
scanArray(arr, n);
printArray(arr, n);
```

> Так работает, да. Но если я меняю n на dm, то после того, как я вводу n,m,k выходит ошибка. А мне нужно чтоб размер массива был в 2 раза больше m.
>
> ```
> int arr[dm];
> scanArray(arr, dm);
> printArray(arr, dm);
> ```

Ну так присваивай их после считывания, а не до.

Comment: Так работает, да. Но если я меняю n на dm, то после того, как я вводу n,m,k выходит ошибка. А мне нужно чтоб размер массива был в 2 раза больше m. 
int arr[dm];


    scanArray(arr, dm);
    printArray(arr, dm);

Comment: Ну так присваивай их после считывания, а не до.

Comment: Вы абсолютны правы, спасибо.

Comment: В таком случае ответ можно принять нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы создаете переменную n, она принимает, можно сказать, случайное, неизвестное вам значение. Поэтому переменная dn  принимает неверное значение. Инициализируйте значение dn после ручного ввода переменной n. Тоже самое с переменными m и dm соответственно.